# How to remove the first Slash after the root directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I visit

```
myexamplesite.com?var/othervar
```

i get redirected to

```
myexamplesite.com/?var/othervar
```

but i want the URL to stay like this: myexamplesite.com?var/othervar

Is it possible to remove the first / after the root url using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is impossible with htaccess and with everything else.

It depends on the browser you are using, that's why the root slash is added automatically.